# Showing custom fields under Related Posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to using Wordpress. I'm trying to look for a plugin or function such that it fetches related posts but instead of showing the usual related post titles, it shows some text from a custom field.

Any way to achieve this?

Thanks
Vila

Answer (score 0):

Download a related posts plugin. I use YARPP (Yet Another Related Posts Plugin). Edit the plugin so that instead of displaying the_title() it displays the custom field you want.

Comment: hi Dan, can you please advise which line of code I can change & in which file. I'm new to this so I'm not sure.